# Input Date greater than date value given

Tags: java

I need to check whether the given date is 2020-10-20T11:10:29-0400 greater than 2020-08-30T12:00:00-0400

all these dates are in EST/EDT timezones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create `DateTimeFormatter` instance and parse `String` date:

```
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ");
    OffsetDateTime dateTime1 = OffsetDateTime.parse("2020-10-20T11:10:29-0400", formatter);
    OffsetDateTime dateTime2 = OffsetDateTime.parse("2020-08-30T12:00:00-0400", formatter);
    System.out.println(dateTime1.isAfter(dateTime2));    // true
    System.out.println(dateTime1.isBefore(dateTime2));   // false
    System.out.println(dateTime1.equals(dateTime2));     // false
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to convert `String` to a `DateTime` object:
`2020-10-20T11:10:29-0400` to `2020-10-20`

```
 Stirng date = "2020-10-20T11:10:29-0400";
 SimpleDateFormat formatter1=new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss-0400");
 SimpleDateFormat formatter2=new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
// .parse(String) it takes String as arrugment 
// and it converts the String date to a Date Object
 Date dummyDate = formatter1.parse(date);
//.format(Date) it takes Date as a arrgumemnt 
// converts Date Object to String  
 Date d1 = formatter2.parse(formatter2.format(dummyDate));
```

do compare dates we can use `.compareTo()` function

`d1.compareTo(d2) > 0` if this is true then "Date1 is after Date2"
`d1.compareTo(d2) < 0` if this is true then "Date1 is before Date2"
`d1.compareTo(d2) == 0` if this is true then "Date1 is equal to Date2"

```
        // compareTo() method
        int diff = date1.compareTo(date2);
        if(diff > 0) {
            System.out.println(date1 + " is greater than " + date2);
        } else if (diff < 0) {
            System.out.println(date1 + " is less than " + date2);
        } else {
            System.out.println(date1 + " is equal to " + date2);
        }
```

You can also use `isAfter()` `isBefore()` `isEqual()` to check which date comes first

```
        LocalDateTime date1 = LocalDateTime.now();
        LocalDateTime date2 = LocalDateTime.of(2020, 1, 31, 10, 15, 45);

        // isAfter() method
        if(date1.isAfter(date2)) {
            System.out.println(date1 + " is after " + date2);
        }

        // isBefore() method
        if(date1.isBefore(date2)) {
            System.out.println(date1 + " is before " + date2);
        }

        // isEqual() method
        if(date1.isEqual(date2)) {
            System.out.println(date1 + " is equal to " + date2);
        }
```